# How Can I get text of all child nodes

Tags: xpath

I want to get the text of a tag and span tag at the same time.

```
    <td class="desc_autoHeight">
                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" target="_blank">Silicon Power</a>
                    <br><span class="FreeGift">48 Hours Only</span>
                </td>

<td class="desc_autoHeight">
                    <a rel="nofollow" href="#" target="_blank">Silicon Power</a>
                    48 Hours Only
                </td>
```

Result should be Silicon Power 48 Hours Only

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath with `concat`

```
 concat(//td[@class='desc_autoHeight']/a/text(), ' ', //td[@class='desc_autoHeight']//span[@class='FreeGift']/text())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Lets say i have 40 <td> which contains 40 a tags but 20 span tag so whats the solution to concatenate these using for loop

Answer (score 0):

If `$td` is the `td` element in question, then `normalize-space($td)` gives you the string you are looking for, at least in this particular example.

In many cases simply using the string value of the element (which you can get using `string()`, but in many cases that's implicit) is adequate. The difference with `normalize-space()` is that it turns chunks of spaces and newlines (like the whitespace before the `<a>` start tag) into a single space, or eliminates it at the start and end.